# Bullet point vertical alignment

Tags: css, bulletedlist

How to vertically align bullet points with text in this code? I can't find the CSS property:

[image: screenshot of bullet points to align]

URL: https://scienceofhappyrelationships.com/mistake-10-neglecting-your-appearance/

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They achieve the bullet points by adding a pseudo object before the `<li>` with the bullet point character which is styled and positioned with the css below

```
.cnt article ul li:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    content: '\f04d';
    color: #408c52;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    line-height: 3em;
    font-size: 5px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

because the rotate raises the bullet point you need to set the centre of the transofmation to be the middle of the bullet point so that the rotate does not change the height so you need to add

`transform-origin: -50%;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! And how to align bullets vertically with the text? The bullets are above the vertical midline of the text.

Comment: for a quick dirty way of doing this you can add a translateY transform to make it more aligned i.e. `transform: translateY(7px) rotate(45deg);`

Comment: See my edit, the non quick and dirty way is to set `transform-origin: -50%;` hope you can make my answer the accepted answer.

Comment: OK, I made your answer the accepted one. Thank you again!